# What Statistical method is necessary to determine the correlation amongst a set of individual correlations?

Tags: correlation

I have a question regarding the statistical method necessary to determine a correlation between a set of individual correlations. Below is an example of a situational question I currently face.

To clarify as requested. I have gathered data on over 400 hotel properties. I then determined if there is a correlation between two variables for each individual  property. 400 correlations are then returned independent of each other. Now lets say if those 400 properties belong to a chain. I would like to see if there is an overall correlation across all of the previous correlations tested for the 400 properties.

Is there a statistical method that describes how to approach this problem?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the correlation amongst a set of individual correlations", & "the overall correlation"? Those don't sound like the same thing. The former sounds like you could correlate two corresponding sets of correlations, whereas the latter could be just the mean.

Comment: Sounds like a meta-analysis question, but that's disregarding the former possibility. I'm guessing the title and first sentence are just worded misleadingly, since they don't match the rest of the question. Please clarify if this is correct by [editing](http://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/108957/edit) the problematic parts, whichever they happen to be.

Comment: @NickStauner there I edited the previous message.

Comment: So you have a vector of >400 correlations...What's the other variable you want to correlate? A dummy code for which chain the correlations are from?

Comment: I have a vector of 400 correlations but no other variable.. So I guess in this case it would be best to determine the mean of the correlations instead? It's a European chain hotel....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to understand the in-store correlation between the pairs of variables (e.g., worked hours vs revenue). Therefore the mean(average) over the 40 correlations (or any statistic of interest - median, percentiles, etc) should give you the answer. Just note that it is not the same as "regardless-of-store" correlation between the variables --- that is the correlation between the two variables independent of the store. That can be computed by concatenating all the data from all stores and computing the correlation on all of it (assuming there is no importance to time).

Comment: If you're suggesting finding the mean of correlations, you should probably mention the [Fisher transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation). This step is too easy to forget otherwise.